# Где хранятся переменные, объявляемые в pascal?

Tags: pascal

Эти переменные хранятся в стеке? Т. е. `x:=43;` записывает в стек число 43? А для чего  pascal импользует регистры процессора?

Comment: Локальные переменные наверняка в стеке. Их адреса будут вычисляться (компилятором на этапе компиляции, а не в ходе работы функции), как смещения от начала текущего стекового фрейма, т.е. регистра указателя стека при входе в функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная x может оказаться как регистром процессора, так и адресом в памяти, все зависит от того как "решит" компилятор.

> А для чего pascal импользует регистры процессора?

Как правило нельзя напрямую например взять значения из двух ячеек памяти, сложить и положить сумму в третью ячейку. Большинство арифметических и логических операций процессор производит между регистрами, т.к. они физически находятся в нем самом, а не где-то "далеко" в оперативке. Поэтому обычно перед операцией значения сначала загружаются в регистры, а потом уже над ними производится операция.

Answer (score 0):

По сути, выражение

```
x:=3
```

Эквивалентно ассемблеровскому муву:

```
mov x, 3
```

Comment: ок. А х-это регистр процессора, или ячека памяти?

Comment: x - это переменная "X"